# List comprehension with loop and conditions

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement, list-comprehension

I'd like to transform this Python code (below) into a list comprehension :

```
def list1(a):
  L = [100]
  n = int((L[0] - a)/0.2)
  for i in range (n):
    var = L[i]-0.2
    var = round(var,2) if var * 100 % 100 != 0 else int(var)
    L.append(var)
  return L

print(list1(25))
```

I've tried that but it didn't work :

```
def list2(a):
  L = [100]
  n = int((L[0] - a)/0.2)
  i = 0
  var = L[i]-0.2
  L = [L[i]-0.2 for i in range (n) round(var,2) if (var) * 100 % 100 != 0 else int(var)]
  return L

print(list2(25))
```

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access a `list` while building the `list` using a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) with `list.extend`. This approach has no advantages over a for loop and is less readable. Using a single list comprehension is [not easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71264771/14277722) in your use case.

```
def list2(a):
  L = [100]
  n = int((L[0] - a)/0.2)
  L.extend(round(L[i]-0.2,2) if (L[i]-0.2) * 100 % 100 != 0 else int(L[i]-0.2) for i in range(n))
  return L
list2(25) == list1(25)
```

Output

```
True
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a list comprehension that gives you the same result (but works differently):

```
def list1(a):
    return [x/5 if x%5 else x//5
            for x in range(500, 5*a-1, -1)]
```

And one working similar to your `for` loop:

```
def list1(a):
  return [round(var,2) if var * 100 % 100 != 0 else int(var)
          for n in [int((100 - a)/0.2)]
          for i in range(1 + n)
          for var in [100 if i == 0 else var-0.2]]
```

But that one is hacky. If the next element depends on the previous element(s), you're really better off with a `for` loop (or even a `while` loop in this case) than with a list comprehension.